# Default error 400 GP clip and ship

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.2, clip

I am running this [script](http://jsbin.com/luvey/1/edit) . I get a 400 error message. The message is the following:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Server environment property not found: requestProperties"]}}
```

I am not sure what it is. I am using the Extract Data Task (Server) tool for 10.2.

Comment: Also posted at [ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/107858-error-400-GP-clip-and-ship) - no responses there yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this myself using the Extract Data Task. As far as I can tell, this just indicates that the job failed. I'd recommend republishing the service with the Message Level set to 'Info' (see screenshot below).

This will print arcpy.AddMessage() statements in your script, and will also help you trace any errors. To see these messages, execute the GeoProcessing service from the REST endpoint by manually entering the parameters, then submitting the job. As you refresh the page, you'll see the various messages from the python script, and ultimately the line that it's crashing on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can  also go to the  http://<>:6080/arcgis/manager

go to  the service >  Parameters >  Properties > Message Level:

and set to  Info  and see  the messages